# Multiple Conditions for COUNT IIF

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to get 2 count columns in an access query I have setup.

I have a count of all employees fitting the criteria, now I need to get a count for 2 different job groups. The codes are for Supervisor Level 1 which is the code 11 and Supervisor Level 5 which is 72-79. I have tried a couple variations of the count IIF and it is not working, are there any thoughts or suggestions?

```
SELECT O896IA_VEMPPRSA.REG_NR, 
  O896IA_VEMPPRSA.DIS_NR, 
  Count(O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR) AS CountOfSYS_EMP_ID_NR
FROM ((O896IA_VEMPPRSA  
  INNER JOIN O867IA_VJOBHST  
  ON O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR = O867IA_VJOBHST.SYS_EMP_ID_NR)  
  INNER JOIN O867IA_VPJOBCO  
  ON O896IA_VEMPPRSA.JOB_CLS_CD = O867IA_VPJOBCO.JOB_CLS_CD)  
  INNER JOIN O867IA_VPJOBCO AS O867IA_VPJOBCO_1  
  ON O867IA_VJOBHST.JOB_CLS_CD = O867IA_VPJOBCO_1.JOB_CLS_CD
WHERE (((O867IA_VJOBHST.REC_EFF_STT_DT)>=#7/1/2012#  
  Or (O867IA_VJOBHST.REC_EFF_STT_DT)>=#1/1/2012#)  
  AND ((O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_EMT_STS_CD)<>"T")  
  AND ((O867IA_VJOBHST.EMP_ACN_TYP_CD)="HIR")  
  AND ((O867IA_VPJOBCO_1.JOB_GRP_CD) In ("11","72","74","77","79")))  
  OR (((O867IA_VJOBHST.REC_EFF_STT_DT)>=#7/1/2012#  
  Or (O867IA_VJOBHST.REC_EFF_STT_DT)>=#1/1/2012#)  
  AND ((O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_EMT_STS_CD)<>"T")  
  AND ((O867IA_VJOBHST.EMP_ACN_TYP_CD)="PRO")  
  AND ((O867IA_VPJOBCO_1.JOB_GRP_CD) In ("11","72","74","77","79")))
GROUP BY O896IA_VEMPPRSA.REG_NR, O896IA_VEMPPRSA.DIS_NR;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code field you're talking about is `JOB_GRP_CD`, which appears to be text datatype.

If that is correct, you can use `Sum` `IIf` instead of the `Count` `IIf` strategy you mentioned by adding two field expressions to the `SELECT` clause.

```sql
SELECT
    O896IA_VEMPPRSA.REG_NR,
    O896IA_VEMPPRSA.DIS_NR,
    Count(O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR) AS CountOfSYS_EMP_ID_NR,
    Sum(IIf(O867IA_VPJOBCO_1.JOB_GRP_CD = '11', 1, 0))
        AS [Supervisor Level 1],
    Sum(IIf(O867IA_VPJOBCO_1.JOB_GRP_CD IN ('72','74','77','79'), 1, 0))
        AS [Supervisor Level 5]
```

But if you prefer `Count` `IIf`, that could also work.

```sql
Count(IIf(O867IA_VPJOBCO_1.JOB_GRP_CD = '11', 1, Null))
```

If I guessed wrong about the field name and/or datatype, adapt one of these patterns with a condition which fits the correct field and datatype.

```sql
Sum(IIf(<condition is True>, 1, 0))
Count(IIf(<condition is True>, 1, Null))
```

Comment: I am getting an error: The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing or the punctuation is incorrect.

Comment: I forgot the comma following `CountOfSYS_EMP_ID_NR`.  I corrected the answer.